# Way to pass arguments to FastAPI app via command line

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn, systemd, uvicorn

I'm using python 3.8.0 for my FastAPI app.
It uses the `.env` file located on the root of a project directory. I am using the dotenv package, and the location of the `.env` file is hardcoded within the app. Here is my unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for my_app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nginx
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/
Environment="PATH=/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/my_app.sock -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The challenge is to run two versions (production and test) of the same app using two different `.env` on two different ports. I'll have to create a second unit file. But how can I pass the name of two diffeent env file names to the app for further usage. These files contain database connections, etc.
I imagine it roughly like this
1st unit file

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn 
--bind unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/my_app.sock -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app --env_file_name=".env.prod"
```

2nd unit file

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn 
--bind unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/my_app/my_app.sock -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app --env_file_name=".env.dev"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the path from which systemd will read the environment for your process exactly in unit file configuration. [The setting is called](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) `EnvironmnetFile=`. Just set the option to the path for `.env.prod` in one unit file and for the path to `.env.test` for another.